# Performance comparison of RetryTemplate vs ErrorHandler

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-retry

I have two ways of recovering from KafkaListener errors with using

1. RetryTemplate in the `KafkaListener` method:

```java
@KafkaListener(topics: "topic1")
public void handle(command) {
    retryTemplate.execute(ctx -> {
        processCommand(command);
    });
    // Retries exhausted, execute the recoverer logic
    recover(command);
}
```

2. Set ErrorHandler to MessageListenerContainer via ContainerCustomizer:

```java
@Component
    public class ContainerCustomizer {
        public ContainerCustomizer(CustomConcurrentContainerListenerFactory factory) {
            factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
                    container.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Exception e) -> {
                        //logic for recoverer after retries exhausted
                        recover(convertRecord(record));
                    }, new ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries(2)));
            });
        }
    }
```

When it comes to performance and blocking the consumer thread, how these two options compare? Is it true to say that with `RetryTemplate.execute`, retries are handled in a separate thread while with `containerListener.setErrorHandler` it blocks the main consumer's thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both will block the consumer thread - otherwise you'd continue processing records and Kafka's ordering guarantees would be lost.

Also, both approaches are deprecated in favor of `DefaultErrorHandler`, which is an evolution of `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`.

The difference between the two is, with `Spring Retry`, all invocations will be retried in memory, so you should make sure the aggregate backoff won't exceed the `max.poll.interval.ms` or the broker will think your server is dead and will perform a rebalance.

`SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`, as well as `DefaultErrorHandler`, will perform a new seek to the broker for each retry, so you just need to make sure the biggest delay plus execution time does not exceed `max.poll.interval.ms`.

If you need `non-blocking retries`, take a look at the [non-blocking retries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic) feature.